# How can I mark messages recived via Slack's RTM API as being read?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have the RTM (Real Time Messaging) API setup and I am receiving events, including message posts, however when I query the `channels.history` endpoint with the `unreads` option set to true, the `unread_count_display` matches the number of items in the history.

How can I mark messages recived via Slack's RTM API as being read?

Comment: Have you try https://api.slack.com/events/im_marked OR https://api.slack.com/methods/im.mark RMI API?

Comment: @vikas Would sending those count against the rate limit for the App? If I am receiving lots of messages, I can see the app exceeding the more than one request a second limit if I had to send a request for each message received.